# Troubleshooting to make a table scrollable with a fixed header

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I create table in my AngularJS project, and I try to make it scrollable table with a fixed header.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

  <table class="table table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Sushi Roll
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'fish'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
          Fish Type
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
        <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // Set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // Set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // Set the default search/filter term

  // Create the list of sushi rolls
  $scope.sushi = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab' },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna' },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel' },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety' },
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab' },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna' },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel' },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety' }
  ];

});
```

**[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/303/)**

I tried this, to make table above scrollable with fixed header:

```
.tbody-fixed  {
  display: block;
   height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here how I used it:

```
   <tbody class="tbody-fixed">
      <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
        <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But it's not looking good. How can I make the table above scrollable with a fixed header?

Answer (score 1):

Try using two tables in two divs.

In the first div, the table will only define the header.

In the second div give `overflow-y:auto` and some `height` to div. and the table will have data.

This is how I would implement it. Please let me know if you fiddle.

Comment: @Michael are you talking about styles or something else. if style those can be handled nicely.

Comment: why do I need to put tables in  two separate divs?